# are there any sharepoint js core libs source maps around?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I see that we can download the debug versions of the js sharepoint libs.
https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.19925.12013/core.debug.js

Since running them from Sharepoint online is not feasible as in hosted sharepoint. I have been trying to find the source maps for it so I can load them in VS code for debugging. Anyone knows where I can find them? Or is that possible with SP online? any workarounds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the ones wondering. A possible workaround for this and for any other sites that have huge minified files you can enable by default the files to be pretty printed.

please check the steps in the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371293/chrome-dev-tools-can-i-always-have-pretty-print-enabled

For the sourcemaps, If anyone know anything about it please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could format the js file so it will be rendered friendly in IE developer tool(and debug), Chrome has similar feature.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know about this feature but that does not really work well for the SP core libs. Since some of them are so big that crashes the dev tools, plus they also don't work that well if you are doing it from vs code.

Comment: Alternatives here are to enable the debug files from the master page, but that involves changing the script manager which also not that feasible. Plus can be really heavy for the browser to handle since you loading these files at run time not just mapping them to the source code.